# How to fix managed c++ assembly referencing specific NuGet package delivered dll version (VS2017)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I am building a managed c++ dll (udnet.dll) that references a Nuget package delivered dll

packages.config

```
<packages>
  <package id="ForeignLanguage" version="2.0.5" allowedVersions="[2,3)" />
</packages>
```

When consumed in the full build the actual version of ForeignLanguage.dll is 2.0.6 as this has had a small bugfix since udnet.dll was built.

However when udnet.dll is loaded is fails because it is looking for 2.0.5

[image]

How can I build udnet.dll so it is not so fussy about the version of ForeignLanguage? I only really want it to fail if the major version mismatches.
i.e. (2.0.0.0)

Comment: Building it is not the problem, nor is udnet.dll.  It is the CLR that gets fussy about finding the wrong version.  A `<bindingRedirect>` in the app's .config file is required to tell it is okay.  Not a great library feature, simply update the reference assembly.  Only ever invoke DLL Hell when you have no choice, this is not one of them.

Comment: @Hans the consuming applications are not under my direct control, I am supplying the library assemblies.

Comment: Sure, that makes it extra specially super duper important that you use the correct reference assembly.  Hard to tell how this went wrong, it almost sounds like you made that 2.0.6 patch but did not also update its Nuget package.

Comment: @Hans I think there must be a misunderstanding here. I only have control over this udent.dll and I want it to not care about the dependency minor version, just like all my c# dll do. I don't have control over what final version of ForeignLangauge.dll gets deployed as that depends on other dll'  dependencies. It could be I am fundamentally misunderstanding this though :)

Comment: My Nuget package is fine, it is just the c++ assembly reference that isn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the ForeignLanguage.dll, I had not set the AssemblyVersion to 2.0.0.0 in AssemblyInfo.cpp

```
#define VER_FILE_VERSION_STR STRINGIZE(GITVERSION_Major) \
"." STRINGIZE(GITVERSION_Minor) \
"." STRINGIZE(GITVERSION_Patch) \
".0"

#define VER_VERSION_STR STRINGIZE(GITVERSION_Major) \
".0.0.0"

[assembly:AssemblyVersion(VER_VERSION_STR)];
[assembly:AssemblyFileVersion(VER_FILE_VERSION_STR)];
```